# Stretch image to viewport maintaining aspect ratio without using object-fit

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I need to place an overlay on top of an image with the same measurements. For this, I'm using an absolutely positioned sibling `div`.

I cannot use `object-fit: contain` as it would not reduce the dimensions of the `img` element itself, causing the overlay to be bigger (as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38934114/placing-elements-over-object-fit-contained-images)). Basically, the image's dimensions drive the entire setup.

This is my current setup.

```css
html, body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
   }

.relative {
 position: relative;
 display: inline-block;
}

.image-portrait {
 display: block;
 height: 100vh;
 max-width: 100vw;
}

.image-landscape {
 display: block;
 width: 100vw;
 max-height: 100vh;
}

.overlay {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: rgb(0,0,0,0.5);
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
 color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="relative">
 <img src="https://www.dailycameranews.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/canon-eos-m50-sample-images-05.jpeg" class="image-portrait"/>
 <div class="overlay">This is an overlay</div>
</div>
```

There are two classes for portrait and landscape images respectively. With JS, it is easy to switch the classes. I'm looking for a CSS only solution.

Comment: If it's easy to get what you want with JS, then why not do that? What is it about the JS solution that you don't like?

Answer (score 0):

With your current code given in the question, you should be able to fix it by adding `width: fit-content` to your `.relative` class styling. With that, your `.relative` parent container will match the width of its contents. So in this case, since the `<img>` is driving the width of the inner contents, the container will match its width, and the overlay will just match the width of the parent container.

See more about the `fit-content` value here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/fit-content.

Comment: `fit-content` works only when the image's native dimensions exceeds the viewport. If the image is smaller, it doesn't stretch it till the viewport.